# Animate horizontal scrollview in android studio

Tags: android, animation, scrollview, objectanimator

Im trying to animate my horiontal scrollView. At the moment its going from left to right perfectly with:

```
HorizontalScrollView headband = findViewById(R.id.scroll);
ObjectAnimator.ofInt(headband, "scrollX", 2000).setDuration(10000).start();
```

Now I want two more things:

- How to do the inverse, from right to left ? I assume using sleep is not a good option
- Ho to know exactly the size of my ScrollView in pixels ? As the 2000 value I'm using is random, just working.

Answer (score 1):

After weeks of struggle here is the solution ! Hope it'll be useful to someone.

```
        HorizontalScrollView headband = findViewById(R.id.scroll);


        animator1 = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(headband, "scrollX",  1700).setDuration(10000);
        animator2 = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(headband, "scrollX",  0).setDuration(10000);

        animator1.start();
        animator1.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                animator2.start();

            }
        });

        animator2.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                animator1.start();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ObjectAnimator`'s `repeatMode` to get it to repeat in the opposite direction and `repeatCount` to get it to continue indefinitely. You can get the scrollable size of your `ScrollView` by calculating `scrollView[0].width - scrollView.width`. Here's how it would look in Kotlin with your variables:

```
ObjectAnimator.ofInt(headband, "scrollX", 0, headband[0].width - headband.width).apply {
    repeatMode = ObjectAnimator.REVERSE
    repeatCount = Animation.INFINITE
    duration = 10000
    start()
}
```

If you're executing this somewhere where the width of the views is not known yet, like in `onCreate()`, them wrap it all in `headband.doOnLayout { <code> }`.